# Newbie questions. Ruby classes implementation by example

Tags: ruby, class, subclass

Before reading. I'm new in Ruby and I trying to learn by examples and exercises. 
I found some exercise, and I'm stuck on it.

Code a Ruby program that simulates a Hotel room lot. User will enter, issued a ticket, exit and of course pay.

Basic Required Scenarios:

User can enter hotel if there is enough rooms.
User can exit, if it paid
User that is already in the Hotel, can’t enter again before exiting.
This what i did:

```
   class Hotel < User
      attr_accessor :room
      def initialize(room)
          @room = []
          super(name)
      end

      def on_entry
          if room.count < 20
          new_array = []
          rooms.each do |space|
              new_array << space
              print("You just rent a room!")
              end
          else
              print("Thank you for coming!")
          end
      end

      def on_exit
          if name.exist
              user.time_dindong 
          else
              puts "Please, pay for room first"
          end
      end
    end

    class User
       attr_accessor :name, :id
       def initialize(name, id)
          @name = name
          @id = id
       end
    end
```

I getting error: Hotel.rb:1:in `': uninitialized constant User (NameError) 
Who can please told me what I doing wrong. If it have another way to do that?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Unrelated, but consider naming: a collection of rooms should probably be something plural, like `rooms`, rather than `room`. What are `new_array` and `new_parking`?

Comment: Dave Newton Thanks man it was my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare User class before Hotel class

```
class User
   attr_accessor :name, :id
   def initialize(name, id)
      @name = name
      @id = id
   end
end

class Hotel < User
  # ...
```

And I don't think you need to extend Hotel from User.  It must be:

```
class Hotel
  # ..
```

Comment: demas thanks man, So how I can use methods of hotel like on_entry if I'll not extend it?

Comment: I think you need to pass User as argument to methods on_entry and on_exit

Comment: I tried and get like you say, but I get error: "undefined method `on_exit or on_entry'". I really don't understand how to do that right...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're defining Hotel as extending User, but then defining User after Hotel. User should be defined before Hotel.

(It's also a bit bizarre to see Hotel inherit from User, but I didn't check the sanity of the rest of your code.)

Comment: Denis thank you. To understand you can just see scenario that I described.